# how to store String,Object pair using jedis. (for regular expression support)

Tags: java, regex, jedis

I have a problem with regular expression search of keys in jedis. (I am noob to jedis, I have though used non-sql dbs earlier)

Below are my undertsanding :

Jedis can store only byt[],byte[] or String,String pair.

Is there a way I can allow regex key search.

Basically I want to know if any one has found a way to store String,Object pair, or has found any other alternative to store enable a regex search on jedis.

I also have seen johm and I am not sure if I can convert every object of mine into a string (I am though concidering jaxb option as end of the day I would store data and not methods.)

Please let me know if there are any suggestions that would allow me to achieve the same.

```
EG : 
my class (of whose object I intend to store : )

Class UserInfo {
// with a constructor

String userName;
int age;
}



My Main class where I use jedis


jedis_Policy.save("bob",new UserInfo("bob",23));
jedis_Policy.save("alice",new UserInfo("alice",23));
jedis_Policy.save("bomo",new UserInfo("bomo",23));


required result : 


UserInfo userInfo = jedis_Policy.search("bo*");

// expected bob and bomo
```

Tia!!!